# Facebook won't log in to new activity - android

Tags: android, facebook, android-fragments

I have a log in activity that connects to Facebook at the moment, after the user logs in I want it to connect to facebook and then I want it to connect to my Activity2  class but currently it redirects back to my original activity instead.

Is their anything wrong I'm doing in this part of my code:

```
  private CallbackManager mCallbackManager;
private FacebookCallback<LoginResult> mCallback=new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
        AccessToken accessToken = loginResult.getAccessToken();
        Profile profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();
        if (profile != null) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), MainActivity2Activity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Checking if profile is null wouldn't work as `ProfileManager` fetches the profile asynchronously and `getCurrentProfile()` would likely return null immediately after logging in.

You could instead check if `loginResult.getAccessToken()` returns a non-null value.